# Source Transformation and Power Output

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuits

In a basic circuit, does making a transformation of voltage source to current source affect the power output of the source? I'm being asked to find the power output of a voltage source and then to confirm that power output by doing a source transformation to a current source. I ask this because the power output is different once i have realized the transformation and i'm very confused about that.
By basic circuit i mean the one below. The power output is different in each case and i can't get why. Isn't it supposed that both circuit are equivalent? If that so, how come the power output of the source is different in each case
[image]

Power output for Voltage source 39.94kW and 
Power output for Current source 59.91W.

I'm sorry if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, source transformation doesn't preserve power dissipated by the *source*. 
Consider the following schematic. The circuits below are thevenin/norton equivalents of each other. Yet only one is dissipating power. What you will notice is that if you attach a load the *load* dissapates the same power in both circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDqG9d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say we attach an 300Ω load.

The power dissipated by the load on the voltage source circuit can be found easily with P = V^2/R.

The power dissipated by the load on the current source circuit can be found easily with P = I^2*R.

---

Plugging in (I skipped a voltage/ current division step), we get:

P = 0.75^2 / 300
and 
P = 0.0025^2 * 300

which both evaluate to 1.875mW.

---

Notice that the voltage and current source dissapate different amounts of power, just like in your example.

I encourage you to find the power dissipated in R13 and R14 in your example. You should find them equal. Also try a special case where your load resistance is the same value as the thevenin/norton resistance. Are the current/voltage source power dissipations still different?

Answer (score 0):

> *Power output for Voltage source 39.94kW and Power output for Current
>   source 59.91W.*

Here's where you are going wrong: -

[image]

The "load" is the 15 ohm resistor and this represents the output.

R11 transforming into R12 is irrelevant because it is what it is, *a transformation* and isn't relevant to anything called "output".

In both cases, the output power is **that produced by the 15 ohm resistor** and not anything to do with the source and any transformations thereof.

Source transformation is just a tool that allows us (typically) to combine multiple sources to make analysis easier and simpler. Once sources are combined, transformations can be reversed and you would get a more realistic picture of true source power dissipation.